# Solving $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\ldots}}}$

Tags: radicals, puzzle, nested-radicals

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\ldots}}}$$

My approach

**1st approach:** 
Let $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+a}} = x$, where $a$ is a result of the lower portion of the continued nested radical and $1+\sqrt{2+a}$ is a perfect square, and $x$ is a number that doesn't contain a radical.

Solving for $a$ gives 7, and $x$ equals to 2.

**2nd approach:** 
Using a software, $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\ldots}}} \approx 1.75793...$

What is the best approach for the nested radicals?

Comment: I think it is enough for me to say $1.757... \approx 2$

Comment: Marking this as duplicate

Comment: How on earth did you solve one equation with two variables?

Comment: neglect x, since x is the result of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+a}}$, where $1 + \sqrt{2+a}$ is a perfect square. $x$ just represent the result of the equation here

Comment: I do not yet understand.. can you write that as edit to your question... Are you saying $1+\sqrt{2+a}$ is a perfect square only for one value of $a$?? How do you even known that $a=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+\cdots}}$ even converge?

Comment: @Praphulla I'll just give $x$ a description for it. It does not mean that I'll solve for both variables. The $a$ is the only value to be calculated.

Comment: @Praphulla for your 1st question: No, I give it a small number(not fraction or decimal) that satisfy $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2 + a}}$. I mean to cancel all the radicals and shoot the values to a single number.

Comment: I think you are missing the point... All I am asking is how do you know $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+\cdots}}}$ is a real number? How do you know it converge??

Comment: I dont know it. I just assumed $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+\cdots}}}$ is a real number and converge.

Comment: You are not supposed to assume something which you do not know that it exists.,,